# AWS Rekognition, how to rename a collection?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I have created a collection in was CLI like so:

```
aws rekognition create-collection --collection-id "collectionName"
```

I would like to rename that collection to another string. I can't find how to do that. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to rename a collection. In order to get the collection to the have a different name would be to completely recreate it with the new name. That would involve re-indexing the faces.